# Fixed marker on google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to replicate fixed marker feature shown in [this JSFIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/UuDA6/), but the marker doesn't seem to render in my html page, despite using the same code. The only thing I have added in addition to js fiddle code is the script source. Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong ?

Here is the code I've copied from [JSFIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/UuDA6/).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        body,html,#map_canvas{height:100%;margin:0;}
#map_canvas .centerMarker{
  position:absolute;
  /*url of the marker*/
  background:url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png) no-repeat;
  /*center the marker*/
  top:50%;left:50%;
  z-index:1;
  /*fix offset when needed*/
  margin-left:-10px;
  margin-top:-34px;
  /*size of the image*/
  height:34px;
  width:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>


    <script>
            function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
             //do something onclick
            .click(function(){
               var that=$(this);
               if(!that.data('win')){
                that.data('win',new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'this is the center'}));
                that.data('win').bindTo('position',map,'center');
               }
               that.data('win').open(map);
            });
      };

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code in the jsfiddle you linked to seems to be working for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery, since you're using `$('<div/>')`..

I ran your file and it worked fine after adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

Let me know if this works for you :)

P.S. You might have missed jQuery since it's included using a dropdown on the left of jsFiddle..

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've added jQuery source before Google maps api source. It's still not working, not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you update your code in your question with your current code? Also, does your javascript console report any errors?

Comment: I needed to add a protocol to the jquery URL (at least in IE). `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"`

Comment: I have missed to add `http:` to the jQuery source url, adding this it works.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `http:` was missing from the jQuery script source in the above code, adding it solves my problem.

here is the updated code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <style>
    body,html,#map_canvas{height:100%;margin:0;}
    #map_canvas .centerMarker{
    position:absolute;
    /*url of the marker*/
    background:url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png) no-repeat;
    /*center the marker*/
    top:50%;left:50%;
    z-index:1;
    /*fix offset when needed*/
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:-34px;
    /*size of the image*/
    height:34px;
    width:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    </style>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>


    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&.js"></script>


    <script>
        function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
             //do something onclick
            .click(function(){
               var that=$(this);
               if(!that.data('win')){
                that.data('win',new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'this is the center'}));
                that.data('win').bindTo('position',map,'center');
               }
               that.data('win').open(map);
            });
      };

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>


</body>
</html>
```